# How to add custom :before and :hover elements in tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to recreate some regular css styles in tailwind, but I am having an issues when it comes to integrating the :before pseudo elements.

This is what I have, but for some reason, when I view it on the browser, nothing happens.

It is supposed to have an underline effect.

```
<p
  className="
          relative transition-all w-min-content
          before:content-none before:w-0 before:h-1 before:absolute before:bottom-0 before:right-0 before:bg-blue-400 before:transition-all before:duration-500
          hover:before:w-full hover:before:left-0 hover:before:bg-red-500
          ">
  Underline
</p>
```

Comment: Could you use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see what CSS has been generated. When I 'translate' it by hand to CSS it behaves OK - red line appearing over half a secod on hover and disappearing to the right on non-hover.

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly setting content as none and that never changes on hover.

Not sure you need to do this since pre-hover you have `w-0`. But just removing `before:content-none` gets this result https://play.tailwindcss.com/rq6j7aBlca